# How to 'save' reactive dataframe as non-reactive in shiny/R

Tags: r, shiny

I have a reactive dataframe called meals().

I would like to be able to treat it as a non-reactive dataframe.

However, `meals2<-as.data.frame(meals())` does not give the expected result.

So, I tried

```
meals2=reactive({
      as.data.frame(meals())
  })
```

and that does not work either, and I think that would give me another reactive dataframe in meals2(), which is not what I want. I know I am misunderstanding some of the basics here. Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: Why do you want a non-reactive dataframe?  Can you provide more context on what you are trying to accomplish?  Perhaps an example explaining what you want the output to be?

Comment: You probably wan to use `isolate` for whatever you're ultimately trying to do.

Comment: @cdeterman: I want a non-reactive dataframe from it because I am trying to build a second table that is non reactive. For example, I want to just add `meals()` to another table called `table2` using `able2$meals <- meals()`, but doesn't that mean I have to use `table2$meals <- reactive({meals()})`, which would make `table2` reactive as well?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor - could you please elaborate?

Comment: @user3795577 without knowing what you're trying to do, no.  Essentially `isolate` takes a reactive value without updating it before using it.  http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/isolation.html