# How to use isolate to make a dataframe non-reactive in R Shiny?

Tags: r, file, csv, input, reactive

I have looked at this question but still cannot seem to get my code to work

[How to 'save' reactive dataframe as non-reactive in shiny/R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651692/how-to-save-reactive-dataframe-as-non-reactive-in-shiny-r)

I am trying to read in a csv file into a Shiny app and then make each cell in the csv file a variable to be used later in the app.  Is this possible?  I have been reading about using isolate() but it has not been working out for me.  Every time I make a variable from a information in the file there is an error that says that it cannot be made due to the file being reactive.  The code I have been using to read in the file is below.  Any help on how to create variables from the contents of the csv would be incredibly helpful.

```
filedata <- reactive({
  inFile <- input$datafile

  if (is.null(inFile))
    return(NULL)

  data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)

}) 
isolate(filedata())
```

In order for this to work I believe the file has to be non reactive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isolate` will not help you here. Its purpose is to make (sections of) reactives not react to changes in the input.

From your description, it seems that you want to have data that you can mutate in some way? If you just need to access cells without changing them, you don't really need to do anything, as long as you are within a reactive environment (i.e. render, observe, reactive, possibly more) Just do

```
filedata()[row, column]
```

to access your cell. For example, if you want to have a reactive with the value of the third cell in the first row, you can do

```
thirdCellInFirstRow <- reactive(filedata()[row, column])
```

then use `thirdCellInFirstRow()` to access that value in another reactive.

If you need to be able change the data in the data set, for example the content of a cell, then you need to use a different structure. One possibility is `reactiveValues` or `reactiveVal`. Create an empty `reactiveValues` in your server function:

```
storedData <- reactiveValues
```

Then you can store your data frame there, for example by using this in your filedata reactive:

```
storedData$df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)
```

Now you can access that data set from other reactive environments as `storedData$df` and read or write data to it.

Comment: If you'd like to know more, I'd recommend reading the reactivity tutorial on the shiny hub and maybe watch the video lectures from ShinyConf. It's a bit unusual at first, but once you get used to it reactivity is very nice to program in.